# How can I style and break the result of a PHP query

Tags: php, css, database, sql-server-2012

Please help me.

I have a PHP code which fetches result from database and display in a website in scrolling form. Now i want to style this marquee

Below is my PHP code

```
<?php
$data_source='ss';
$user='su';
$password='pass';

// Connect to the data source and get a handle for that connection.
$conn=odbc_connect($data_source,$user,$password);
if (!$conn){
    if (phpversion() < '4.0'){
      exit("Connection Failed: . $php_errormsg" );
    }
    else{
      exit("Connection Failed:" . odbc_errormsg() );
    }
}
$sql="SELECT MARKETNAME, COMMODITY, MAXPRICE
FROM(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY commodity ORDER BY Date desc ,maxprice Desc) rn
    FROM markets where NOT date=DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0, GETDATE()), 0) and commodity IN('Bengal gram','Bajra','Black gram','Green gram','Copra','Horse    gram','Tur','Jowar','Ragi','Maize','Paddy','Groundnut','Safflower','Sesamum','Sunflower','Dry Chilli','Tamarind','Turmeric','Arecanut','Coconut','Red gram','Cotton','Jaggery'))X
WHERE rn=1";

# Execute the statement.
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

// Fetch and display the result set value.
if (!$rs){
    exit("Error in SQL");
}
echo '<marquee onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">';
echo '<a href="http://localhost:/show2.php">';
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($rs) ) {
$res=implode("->",$row);
echo '|';
print_r($res);
echo "|";
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
//echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
echo '</a>';
echo '</marquee>';
// Disconnect the database from the database handle.
odbc_close($conn);
?>
```

The output of above program look like this

```
 |marketname->commodity->maxprice|  ......
```

I want like this

```
commodity(marketname)   |   commodity(marketname)   |  ........
      maxprice          |          maxprice         |
```

Here **commodity(marketname)** should be in bold and different color. And **maxprice** in regular size and different color.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You would do it by applying css to the generated html. A decent tutorial would be a good place to start https://duckduckgo.com/?q=css+tutorial

Comment: Hmm, after looking at your code, you probably need a PHP tutorial too. http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: @vascowhite Thanks for the reply. How to break the content of marquee?

Comment: Sorry Im new to this field

Comment: The fact that you implode  the result set, then ask how to break it, shows me that you really need to look at the PHP tutorial site I linked to.

Comment: Yes sir, I know the functionality of implode. But Now Im asking about how to achieve this because I dnt knw much functions of PHP since Im a beginner  whtevr the code I had written was from research only not my own code.

Comment: I assumed that was the case. Do some tutorials and learn to code then come back if you still have problems.

Comment: Ok Thank you for ur precious time :)

Comment: Hello sir, How can I get the column name along with this result? My output is still on same line that's ok but now I need the result with column name. How can I do that? @vascowhite

Answer (score 0):

try this inside marquee tags,

```
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($rs) ) {

$commodity=$res['COMMODITY'];
$market_name=$res['MARKETNAME'];
$max_price=$res['MAXPRICE'];

echo '|';
echo  $commodity."(".$market_name.")";    
echo '|';
echo $max_price;    
//echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

Comment: Im getting result as |0|__|0|__|0|__